# onClick inside post_content does not appear in post tinymce editor

Tags: tinymce, post-editor

I'm doing a migration. 
I made a PHP script to generate posts in the new WordPress database.
The post content contains an HTML link containing `href="javascript:"` and `onClick="trackOutboundLink('url')"`.

**post_content in the new database**

```
<div>
  <a class="exclusive button-exclusive" href="javascript:" onclick="trackOutboundLink('url'); return false;" rel="nofollow"><span>&#9655; Text link</span></a>
</div>
```

For some reason, the `href` and `onclick` attributes did not show in the admin post editor. Why? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, TinyMCE sets [`allow_script_urls`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/url-handling/#allow_script_urls) to `false`, which is what is causing the `href` attribute and value in the link to be removed.

Also in the interest of best practices, [TinyMCE does not allow the `onlcick` attribute on links](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#schema) by default. This can be changed too.

The `tiny_mce_before_init` hook can be used to change TinyMCE's options so that this content is not removed:

```
/**
 * Filters the TinyMCE config before init.
 *
 * @param array  $mceInit   An array with TinyMCE config.
 * @param string $editor_id Unique editor identifier, e.g. 'content'.
 */
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse_tiny_mce_before_init', 10, 2 );
function wpse_tiny_mce_before_init( $mceInit, $editor_id ) {
    // Allow javascript: in href attributes.
    $mceInit['allow_script_urls'] = true;

    // Allow onclick attribute in anchor tags.
  if ( ! isset( $mceInit['extended_valid_elements'] ) ) {
        $mceInit['extended_valid_elements'] = '';
    } else {
        $mceInit['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',';
    }
    $mceInit['extended_valid_elements'] .= 'a[href|rel|class|id|style|onclick]';

    return $mceInit;
}
```