# How to create an onclick event on an image in a post?

Tags: functions

This is what it should be:

```
<img onclick="og_load();"  style="cursor: pointer;" src="wp-content/uploads/2018/04/downloadnow1.png" alt="" width="455" height="116">
```

But it keeps changing in:

```
<img style="cursor: pointer;" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/downloadnow1.png" alt="" width="455" height="116" />
```

I assume something has to be added in the functions.php but the solution is above my knowledge, anyone could lend me a hand?

Cheers.

**Edit:**
Hmm I read slightly different questions but all stated it has some to do with the WP text editor.

And the code is to call a content locker of which the script I added to the head tag.

In a static site I already got it working but because the editor is keep changing the code it will not call the locker.

I tried this to remove the tag limitation

> Method 1: Disable WordPress filtering of script tags
>
> If you trust that your authors won’t get themselves into trouble, you
>   can disable the blocking of script tags from within JavaScript. In
>   wp-config.php within your root web directory, you’ll need to enable
>   custom tags by adding the following line of code:
>
> define( 'CUSTOM_TAGS', true );
>
> Within your functions.php page, you can add the following code:
>
> function add_scriptfilter( $string ) { global $allowedtags;
>   $allowedtags['script'] = array( 'src' => array () ); return $string; }
>   add_filter( 'pre_kses', 'add_scriptfilter' );

Unfortunately that gave this error:

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/a7480/public_html/wp-includes/kses.php on line 1416
```

And to clarify it's an image in a post that when clicked needs to call the content locker.

**Update:**

Ok this is weird, When I replace the image url in "inspect element" with

```
<img onclick="og_load();"  style="cursor: pointer;" src="wp-content/uploads/2018/04/downloadnow1.png" alt="" width="455" height="116">
```

It does work...

Now to find out how to let it actually work.

**Last Update:**
Sweet mother of God I finally got it to work, the only thing that sucks is if I switch to visual editor it strips the code.

Comment: Can you post your PHP code for outputting the image? This is not enough to provide help/guidance

Comment: Sorry I don't know which PHP code you are referring to. I'm not the greatest WP expert obviously :)

Comment: IMHO, you're not going to fix the issue by manually editing things (well, you might, but it will take a lot of time). By using the guidance of my solution, you will be able to fix all future instances of the issue. (This is assuming that you need to 'fix' all instances of an img tag in all posts.) Even then, one could fine-tune the solution to only apply to images where you have manually put a specific 'class' in the images you want to add that onclick function to. But the issue needs to be fixed 'programmatically', not manually. And that will take some PHP knowledge, from you or someone else.

Comment: The visual editor strips `onclick` by default. This behavior can be overridden using the `tiny_mce_before_init`. You should be able to adapt [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/299358/2807) so that it targets `img` tags rather than links.

Answer (score -1):

Without specifics, in general, the page code that is output is generated by your theme code. So you would need to look into the theme's template that is used for that page.

The template used is determined by the WordPress Theme Heirarchy , details are here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ ; take a look at the graphic which will help you understand which template is being used.

Then, look at that template file to find what is outputting the 'img' tag. That will take a bit of digging. Once you find that code, post it here to get more help.

It is also possible to use the DOM object to modify all 'img' tags with some Javascript, but that will affect all 'img' tags, which may not be what you want. Lots of tutorials on how to do that.

But without more detail of the code that is generating the 'img' tag, it is hard to give you a definitive answer. The above process will help you figure out what that code is.

**Added**

Here's some code that will change the 'class' attribute in a DOM object:

```
function fix_img_tag() {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false); // supress errors
    $dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_NOERROR);  // supress errors
    // img = change class to myclass (removing any other class statement)
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {
        $node->setattribute('class','myclass');

        $dom->saveHtml($node) ;
    }   
    $html = $dom->saveHTML();   // saves the object (all of the html) so we can return it   
    return $html;
}
```

Based on that code, and the DOM Object itself, you should be able to figure out how to add the onclick element to the img tag. Note that the above code will change **all** img tags.

Then just figure out how to add the function to the_content() filter... hint: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

DOM is an interesting thing to know about. Lots of stuff you can do with the DOM object.

(Note that I am giving you guidance on how to learn how to do the task, and to implement it. It is good to learn things.)

Comment: To me it sounded more like the `<img>` is in the post content. Thus the part about the template hierarchy is irrelevant.

Comment: It is not clear what the OP is referencing. I saw it as a theme template issue. You didn't. Not a good reason for a downvote of my answer, IMHO, especially  since my concluding paragraph said that more info is needed.

Comment: The image is indeed in the post content.

Comment: Then perhaps this will help: https://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-change-img-tag-html/ , which shows how to add a filter that will change the img tag. This post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81522/change-html-structure-of-all-img-tags-in-wordpress will get you started on how to use the DOM object to change all img tags to add the on-click event. It depends on when you want to add that onclick parameter to the img tag; on post 'save' or post 'view'. I'd personally use the DOM object, since it appears that you want to add that function for all img tags.

Comment: Cheers Rick, I'm going to check it out right away.

Comment: Ugh, took a read of it all but too complicated for such a little thing. I hope I find someone who knows exactly what I mean and paste something I can copy.

Thank you for your time though,